# I need to use /index as part of url on nuxt2

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Task request path rendering xxx.com/index/news, xxx.com/index/User this effect,I set the file tree to:

```
pages/
--| index/
-----| News/
-------| index.vue
-----| User/
-------| index.vue
--| index.vue
```

But I can't successfully jump to other pages except the root directory.

What do I need to make the path of the webpage show the desired effect?

Comment: What error do you have exactly? Does the page work loading from the url directly? Are they correctly generated in the file `.nuxt/routes.json`? Have you tried to do `/index/news.vue` instead?

Comment: @Kapcash I found the reason,When I named the homepage `index.vue`, then created the index folder and put other pages in it, those pages that should have been created could not be generated,After I try to rename the `index.vue` of the root directory to `home.vue`, other pages can be generated normally,But the path of the home page becomes`/home`;How should I use this path structure without adding any suffix to display the homepage?or discard `/index`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The home page (at the root path) can safely be named `index.vue`, there is no other way to bind a page to the `/` path.

But indeed, the problem is that **you can't have both a page and a folder named the same**. They will overlap.

A solution for this can be to use a custom routing from the `nuxt.config.js` to map the root path `/` to your home page:

```js
router: {
  extendRoutes (routes, resolve) {
     routes.push(
        {
          name: 'index_home',
          path: '/',
          component: resolve(__dirname, 'pages/home.vue')
        },
     )
  }
},
```

See [`nuxt.config.js / router` documentation](https://v2.nuxt.com/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-router#extendroutes)

Note: you could also remove the automatically created `/home` route from here, it will be in the `routes` array.